# TensorFlow 2 Quantization Aware Training (QAT) with tf.GradientTape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, quantization

Can anyone point to references where one can learn how to perform Quantization Aware Training (QAT) with `tf.GradientTape` on TensorFlow 2?

I only see this done with the tf.keras API. I do not use `tf. keras`, I always build customized training with `tf.GradientTape` provides more control over the training process. I now need to quantize a model but I only see references on how to do it using the `tf. keras` API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the official examples [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_example), they showed QAT training with `model. fit`. Here is a demonstration of **Quantization Aware Training** using `tf.GradientTape()`. But for complete reference, let's do both here.

---

Base model training. This is directly from the [official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_example). For more details, please check there.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

# Load MNIST dataset
mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

# Normalize the input image so that each pixel value is between 0 to 1.
train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

# Define the model architecture.
model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
  keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
  keras.layers.Flatten(),
  keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

# Train the digit classification model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(
  train_images,
  train_labels,
  epochs=1,
  validation_split=0.1,
)
```

```
10ms/step - loss: 0.5411 - accuracy: 0.8507 - val_loss: 0.1142 - val_accuracy: 0.9705
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f9ee970ab90>
```

#### QAT `.fit`.

Now, performing **QAT** over the base model.

```
# -----------------------
# ------------- Quantization Aware Training -------------
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

quantize_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model
# q_aware stands for for quantization aware.
q_aware_model = quantize_model(model)

# `quantize_model` requires a recompile.
q_aware_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

q_aware_model.summary()
train_images_subset = train_images[0:1000] 
train_labels_subset = train_labels[0:1000]
q_aware_model.fit(train_images_subset, train_labels_subset,
                  batch_size=500, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1)


356ms/step - loss: 0.1431 - accuracy: 0.9629 - val_loss: 0.1626 - val_accuracy: 0.9500
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f9edf0aef90>
```

Checking performance

```
_, baseline_model_accuracy = model.evaluate(
    test_images, test_labels, verbose=0)

_, q_aware_model_accuracy = q_aware_model.evaluate(
   test_images, test_labels, verbose=0)

print('Baseline test accuracy:', baseline_model_accuracy)
print('Quant test accuracy:', q_aware_model_accuracy)

Baseline test accuracy: 0.9660999774932861
Quant test accuracy: 0.9660000205039978
```

---

#### QAT `tf.GradientTape()`.

Here is the **QAT** training part on the base model. Note we can also perform custom training over the base model.

```
batch_size = 500

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images_subset,
                                                     train_labels_subset))
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size, 
                                    drop_remainder=False)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

for epoch in range(1):
    for x, y in train_dataset:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            preds = q_aware_model(x, training=True)
            loss = loss_fn(y, preds)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, q_aware_model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, q_aware_model.trainable_variables))
        
_, baseline_model_accuracy = model.evaluate(
    test_images, test_labels, verbose=0)

_, q_aware_model_accuracy = q_aware_model.evaluate(
   test_images, test_labels, verbose=0)

print('Baseline test accuracy:', baseline_model_accuracy)
print('Quant test accuracy:', q_aware_model_accuracy)
```

```
Baseline test accuracy: 0.9660999774932861
Quant test accuracy: 0.9645000100135803
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, M.Innat. I will give your suggestion a try and report back here. The problem I have is that the model I work with only builds on the TF functions such as tf.keras.layers.Dense, never keras.Sequential. I'm not even familiar with using keras.Sequential, although I know it's supposed to be easier. What I will do is to translate the model building with tf.keras.layers.Dense into keras.Sequential and then follow your suggestion.

Comment: Feel free to ask. If I can help, I sure will. -)